# Handling Exception From C Function

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a function that is calling a function from a C library. Is there anyway that I can catch that exception from the Postgres function that's calling the C function?

Here's the function that I'm calling:

```
-- Function: public.st_makevalid(geometry)

-- DROP FUNCTION public.st_makevalid(geometry);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.st_makevalid(geometry)
 RETURNS geometry AS
'$libdir/postgis-2.0', 'ST_MakeValid'
  LANGUAGE c IMMUTABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.st_makevalid(geometry) OWNER TO postgres;
COMMENT ON FUNCTION public.st_makevalid(geometry) IS 'args: input - Attempts to make an         invalid geometry valid w/out loosing vertices.';
```

Here is the function that I'm calling it from:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.mango_repair(geometry)
  RETURNS geometry AS
$BODY$
    DECLARE
        the_geom geometry := $1;
        reason text := ST_IsValidReason(the_geom);
    BEGIN
        IF reason LIKE 'Self-intersection%' THEN
            the_geom = ST_MakeValid(ST_Boundary(the_geom));
        END IF;
        RETURN the_geom;
    EXCEPTION
        WHEN OTHERS THEN
            RAISE NOTICE 'something went wrong';
            RETURN the_geom;
    END;
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql STABLE STRICT
  COST 100;
ALTER FUNCTION public.mango_repair(geometry) OWNER TO postgres;
```

And here's how I'm calling it from SQL:

```
UPDATE "test_layer" SET the_geom = mango_repair(the_geom) WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(the_geom);
```

When I run that SQL I get the following error and the mango_repair function doesn't enter the EXCEPTION block as expected.

Here is the error message that I'm receiving:

```
ERROR:  Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)


********** Error **********

ERROR: Geometry type (MultiLineString) does not match column type (MultiPolygon)
SQL state: 22023
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm guessing what you mean correctly, then I suspect you have a PostgreSQL function implemented in C that is raising a PostgreSQL exception. If so, you can't catch and handle that in normal SQL - but you can use a PL/PgSQL `BEGIN ... EXCEPTION` block. See the PL/PgSQL documentation for details on its exception handling features.

Further discussion revealed that the real problem is nothing to do with exception handling, and is in fact a mismatch between geometry types in the `UPDATE` query the function is being called from.

Comment: I already tried doing that with the following function, but it never enters the exception block: http://pastebin.com/egeAmepD

Comment: I also tried wrapping just the ST_MakeValid call in a BEGIN/EXCEPTION block but that didn't raise the notice either. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: @ChrisInCambo Those are useful details to mention in your question. Please amend your question - while you're at it, add the **full, exact text of the error message you are getting** and your PostgreSQL version. Way too much guesswork is involved in interpreting your question right now. Please provide *details* - what's your function, what's this "C language" function, etc. Am I guessing correctly that you're talking about a simple PostGIS C function callable from SQL, or is this something else?

Comment: @ChrisInCambo Oh, BTW, the PL/PgSQL function you linked to is doing text comparisons against human-readable messages. You need to verify that those messages are never translated when you're running PostgreSQL on computers configured for other languages; if those messages are translated then your code won't work on machines where PostgreSQL isn't in English. See if you can find an equivalent function that gives an error code or error number instead of a string and use that if there is one.

Comment: Thanks Craig, I've updated the question with all of the details that you asked for.

Comment: Ok... problem elimination. What about a simple `SELECT mango_repair(the_geom) FROM test_layer WHERE NOT ST_IsValid(the_geom);`, see whether the issue is really the `UPDATE` rather than the function.

Comment: Good spot! SELECT doesn't return the error, so the error is in fact that the type returned by the function can't be inserted as it's not the correct type!

Comment: @ChrisInCambo ... and this is why you include the query and full error message in your initial questions.